# How to cast collection of one type to collection of another?

Tags: java, collections, casting

I want to limit addition to existing collection to elements of certain type. Type is compatible with existing element type, it it it's subclass. So, I want to exclude some superclass types of being added to collection.

How to accomplish this?

I don't want to reput elements from one collection to another, I want to create representation.

Of course I can create representation class myself. But I wonder whether ones exist already on commons library or somewhere else?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are trying to do, maybe using pseudo-code?

Comment: what collection to which ?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question but...um...use generics?

Answer (score 0):

You want a restricted collection **backed** by a more general one, allowing modification to be passed to the original class:

```
    Set<Number> numbers = new HashSet<>();
    Collections.addAll(numbers, 23, 0.3, new BigDecimal("3.254"), 0.1f);
    SubCollection<Number, Integer> integers = new SubCollection<>(numbers);
    integers.add(4);
    //integers.add(3.4); // No longer allowed

/**
 * @param B the element type of the original collection.
 * @param T the element type of this collection.
 */
public class SubCollection<B, T extends B> implements Collection<T> {

    final Collection<B> collection;

    SubCollection(Collection<B> collection) {
        this.collection = collection;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return collection.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return collection.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return collection.contains(o);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] toArray() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T[] toArray(T[] ts) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(T e) {
        return collection.add(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        return collection.remove(o);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> clctn) {
        return collection.containsAll(clctn);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends T> clctn) {
        return collection.addAll(clctn);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> clctn) {
        return collection.removeAll(clctn);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> clctn) {
        return collection.retainAll(clctn);
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        collection.clear();
    }
}
```

A bit much code for specifying that an `add` is restricted (to Integer).

If no modifications are concerned **Java 8** with its **streams** make it simple.